# Ways in c# to input code line

Tags: c#

How I can shorten this into one line:

```
Console.Write("Enter 1 number > ");
int num1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.Write("Enter 2 number > ");
int num2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.Write("Enter 3 number > ");
int num3 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Comment: Do you mean one line of code or one line of output?

Comment: Don't attempt to reduce every program to a single line of code. You may well want to put that code in a loop, but even that loop would probably be no shorter - maybe a single line shorter...

Comment: maybe he want something like "Enter 3 Numbers > " and then parse it , but who knows...

Comment: Looks like homework.

Comment: I mean like the last guy "Enter 3 numbers >"

Comment: @tomer Then just print that to the screen and keep the 3 lines that read and parse ints.

Comment: So you want that in one line? Fine: `Console.Write("Enter 1 number > ");int num1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());Console.Write("Enter 2 number > ");int num2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());Console.Write("Enter 3 number > ");int num3 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter 3 numbers:");

int number1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int number2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int number3 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

If you want the user to put the numbers in a single line (separated by spaces), do the following:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter numbers:");

string line = Console.ReadLine();

string[] parts = line.Split(' '); //numbers are separated by spaces

int[] numbers = parts.Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray();
```